# Using docker for aws command line utility

Tags: docker

This command works as expected:

```
# docker run --rm -it public.ecr.aws/aws-cli/aws-cli:2.9.1 --version
aws-cli/2.9.1 Python/3.9.11 Linux/5.15.0-1026-aws docker/aarch64.amzn.2 prompt/off
```

But this does not:

```
# docker run --rm -it public.ecr.aws/aws-cli/aws-cli:2.9.1 s3 ls
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

Nor can I configure AWS credentials...

```
# docker run -it public.ecr.aws/aws-cli/aws-cli:2.9.1 aws configure
```

I am not sure how to use docker for aws command.

---

Update:

This seems to work as expected:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws  public.ecr.aws/aws-cli/aws-cli:2.9.1 s3 ls
```

But in my case, I do not have credentials saved locally. Isn't the docker container recommended in such cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running this command:

```
docker run --rm -it public.ecr.aws/aws-cli/aws-cli:2.9.1 s3 ls
```

That doesn't work because it does not have access to either your AWS configuration in `$HOME/.aws` nor to environment variables such as `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

If you have your credentials in environment variables, you can expose them to the container using the `-e` option to `docker run`:

```
docker run --rm -it -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY \
  public.ecr.aws/aws-cli/aws-cli:2.9.1 s3 ls
```

Alternatively, you can expose your `~/.aws` directory as you have shown in your recent edit to your answer:

```
docker run --rm -it -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws \
  public.ecr.aws/aws-cli/aws-cli:2.9.1 s3 ls
```